# how to get past days from current time

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I get Current date and time by this code:

```
`var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
 Logger.log(formattedDate)`
```

I want to get date in last 8 days or any last date example this code give me `2021-09-18T22:17:00Z` I want result like that `2021-09-10T22:17:00Z` . first date -8 days

I'm using Google App Script

Answer (score 0):

```js
let d = new Date();
d.setDate(d.getDate()-8);
console.log(d);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I using app script google this code is not work give me ` Fri Sep 10 2021 23:33:22 GMT+0100 (GMT+01:00) `

Comment: Try Utilities.formatDate(d, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'") using d from the example above.  Keep in mind Utilities.formatDate() does not return a date it simple returns a string.